# Nginx 502 bad gateway + PHP 7.2 FPM

Tags: php, nginx

I've been trying to figure out this issue I have with Nginx getting a 502 bad gateway.

The toughest part is the logs are pretty much useless for this.

I am using VueJS, so the request/response is more of a REST architecture.

[image: Here is an example of the]

What it currently is doing is simply trying to return company information, but I get a gateway error. The problem is, this is completely random.

(Note: The CORS error is occurring because of the 502 Bad Gateway)

It will happen only sometimes, but not all the time. When I put the request through a chrome extension called Restlet Client works perfectly fine.

[image]

Reviewing Nginx Errors, it is the Peer Reset Connection:

2019/01/13 14:40:07 [error] 5467#5467: *537 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.252.1, server: _, request: "GET /v1/company/index/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "whitty.vm:130", referrer: "http://whitty.vm:8080/company"

The PHP FPM Error that appears is:

[13-Jan-2019 14:40:07] WARNING: [pool www] child 6063 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 9328.151921 seconds from start
[13-Jan-2019 14:40:07] NOTICE: [pool www] child 6410 started

Does anyone have any clues as to why this may be occurring, do you require anymore information?

Comment: This is from nginx not accepting your app server's response (Laravel?); you need to handle CORs.

Comment: I do handle cors, that acutally works fine. No not Laravel, custom framework

Comment: Apparently not, Tim. In fact, you're adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your request headers when that's actually a response header. Good luck.

Comment: I removed them. Error still occurred. Having said that, I did an Empty Cache and Hard Reload on Chrome and removed the cookies. Would the Chrome cache or sessions have an affect do you think?

Comment: Interestingly enough, the phpmyadmin cookies I have appear to be affecting the result.

Comment: Nope, still having the same issue, but now with a different point

Answer (score 0):

So 502 Nginx Errors can be very hard to diagnose. After countless amounts of research on the web, I came to the conclusion that each 502 Bad Gateway can be caused by a variety of problems.

In my circumstance, I use RedbeansPHP which is DB Layer. When a user logs in, I store their information into $_SESSION. But, rather than picking out what information I should only store into the session, I simply store the RedbeansPHP object into the session.

After changing it to an array and then storing, I no longer have the issue.